# Ubuntu Server 16 not detecting hard drive

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive

I am running two IBM servers, IBM x306m & x366.
I have tried to install Ubuntu server but the hard drives aren't being detected. I was reading on it and I tried to put the x306m in raid 1, it is finished but still does not detect the hard drive. I am only new to raid. It is still in 'REBUILDING' Status, does this mean i cannot detect it because it is still rebuilding?

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly advise waiting until the RAID has been fully built. Depending on how large the drives are this could take a while but any hacks to get around that and install the OS on a half built RAID will only result in headaches further down the line.

It's possible that the OS is not detecting the devices to save you from future issues.

Comment: The drives are both 300gb, I will wait It out and see what happens, if it still doesn't work I will buy some new drives